# What's the purpose of first yod in Eideihen - Avodah Zarah 2a

Tags: grammar-dikduk

עידיהן Referred to in Talmud (Avodah Zarah 2a) which is derived from Isaiah 43:9  have twoי (yods) whereas the one in Isaiah 43:9 is without the first yod ( עדיהם).The enlarged letters (witness) in Shema (עד) is also without this yod. What is the purpose of the first yod and why is scripture always indicating witness without this yod everywhere where witness is mentioned? Example Genesis 21:30 Avraham says that they may witness to me (לעדה)

Comment: It's pretty common in texts without niqqud to include extra matres lectionis to help clarify proper pronunciation. I didn't check your examples, but could that be it? Are you familiar with that phenomenon?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. Actually its in Tanakh with niqqud  (Isaiah 43:9) . But I guess if the chachamim argued it out on the level of (First Aleph vs Ayin) and found no problem with it ,there is more that I still have to learn in this regard. (Beezrat Hashem)